# Batch Script Programming -- Any way to change the line of where to echo?

Tags: batch-file, command, echo, goto

Basically, I have a section where I need to loop until the user supplies valid input, but if they continuously supply invalid input and I just keep asking for the `SET /P MYVAR="Selection? "` it prints it on a new line everytime, causing a scroll...

I'd much rather do:

```
:SELECTION
SET /P MYVAR="Selection? "

IF ERROR HERE ( //I realize this is pseudo code for the error check
    ECHO MAKE A VALID SELECTION...
    MOVE UP 2 ROWS?
    GOTO :SELECTION
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `cls` to clear the screen and rewrite it again like this:

```
:SELECTION
SET /P MYVAR="Selection? "

IF ERROR HERE ( //I realize this is pseudo code for the error check
    ECHO MAKE A VALID SELECTION...
    MOVE UP 2 ROWS?
    cls
    GOTO :SELECTION
)
```

This way the user just continually sees "Selection? " if they make an invalid input.

Answer (score 1):

If this is [ANSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) compatible terminal you can do something like this:

```
ECHO <CSI>[2A
```

Where `<CSI>` is usually the escape character 27.

Same in a Mac OS X terminal:

```
$ echo -e "\0033[2A"
```

Comment: Nice idea, but Windows doesn't support this (anymore)